# Why is it necessary to return "self" in magic method overloading?

Tags: python

I'm overloading the `__iadd__` magic method for a class, and unless I return self it fails with the error that I can't add `NoneType` and `str`.  I can infer from the error that because I'm not returning `self`, the implicitly returned `None` can't be added.  I'm performing an in-place change howerver, and so I'm more interested in what's  happening under the hood.  Here is a sample method that adds lists of dict objects:

```
class StageChanges(LeverObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('stage_changes')
        self.stage_changes = []

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.stage_changes.extend(other)
        return self
```

Comment: Overriding you mean? Edit: nvm it's clear enough what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the documentation says:

> These methods [the `__i*__` methods] are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (+=, -=, *=, /=, //=, %=, **=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, |=). These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self).

They don't have to return `self`, but they do have to return the result, because that result is then assigned back to the target on the left side of the equals sign.  In other words, `__iadd__(x, y)` has to return the result of `x+y` just like `__add__(x, y)` has to return the result of `x+y`.  It's just `__iadd__` *may*, *in addition* mutate the left-hand operand if it wants to.

Or, as you'll no doubt see if you look for other questions about this, `x += y` is not, as some people think, equivalent to `x.__iadd__(y)`.  It is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`.

Answer (score 1):

In `x += y`, even if `x` supports `__iadd__`, it's not assumed that `x` will remain the same object after the operation. `__iadd__` has the option of returning a new object for `x`, and that object could be `None`. For disambiguation, `__iadd__` must return `self` if `x` should still be `self`.